How to stop LSP from turning an entire uncompleted method call red?
When I write a method but don't finish it, the language server gets mad and turns the whole thing red, making it difficult to read. I don't have any screenshots because my computer can't currently take screenshots, but as an example, the following is all red in my nvim:
print(
        asd,
        nonsense=whatever
)

I would prefer that it keep the red squiggly underline but not turn the actual text red.
Sorry that I don't have screenshots. I'm using lspconfig, and my config files are at https://github.com/L3eC/nvim-again

What do you want the language server to do instead?

edited OP to answer this question

Do I understand correctly that you only want the error highlighted in a different way?

I'd like the actual text (i.e. print(asd,nonsense=whatever)) to be highlighted differently.
